# Does DynamoDb update anything if no changes have been made?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does DynamoDb update a record if no changes have been made in an `UpdateItemRequest`?

For example, if the table contains a record as follows:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "alice"
}
```

And the update request is as follows:

```
String expression = "set #n = :n"
HashMap<String, String> expressionAttributeNames = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeNames.put("#n", "name");
HashMap<String, AttributeValue> expressionAttributeValues = new HashMap<>();
expressionAttributeValues.put(":n", AttributeValue.builder().s("alice").build());
UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest =
        UpdateItemRequest.builder()
            .tableName(tableName)
            .key(key)
            .updateExpression(expression)
            .expressionAttributeNames(expressionAttributeNames)
            .expressionAttributeValues(expressionAttributeValues)
            .build();
dynamoDbClient.updateItem(updateItemRequest);
```

In this case the name remains "alice", nothing has been changed. Does DynamoDb treat this as an update or does it treat it as nothing? I am asking because I wonder if DynamoDb streams will be triggered with this request.

Comment: @luk2302 it is useful to have an answer to this without going through the trouble of trying it out.

Comment: That is why you can self-answer. This will teach *you* something as well, trying it out, finding it our for yourself and then sharing your result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html#Streams.Processing) the stream will **not** be triggered if `UpdateItem` does not change any data in the item:

> If you perform a PutItem or UpdateItem operation that does not change
>   any data in an item, DynamoDB Streams does not write a stream record
>   for that operation.